# Calling stored procedure from web app Jasper report returns no data

Tags: java, jsp, stored-procedures, jasper-reports

I have a Jasper report which is called from my web app and executes a stored procedure to get its data. The stored procedure works on SQL Developer and iReports Studio (5.1) but after building and deploying, it only returns a blank pdf when I call the report from the JSP front end.

The log files indicate that the parameters are correctly sent, but there is no data for the Jasper library's `JRVerticalFiller` class.

```
conn  = dataSource.getConnection();

parameters.put("REPORT_CONNECTION", conn);
parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", propsUtil.getReportsRootpath());

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, conn);

JRPdfExporter jrPdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter();

jrPdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
//etc ...

jrPdfExporter.exportReport();
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: it will be difficult to tell with this given information, is it possible to share the code spinet ?

Comment: Can you check if the path is proper: `propsUtil.getReportsRootpath()`, try to just print some static content and see if that works. If you are using `jrxml` than try to just have some static content in the file.

Comment: getReportsRootPath returns the correct folder location. From stepping through the jasper source code, the log statement says no data. Which is strange because running the stored procedure in SQL Developer confirms that there is data.

Comment: Make sure the connection object passed is correctly initialized

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem. The parameter names defined in the stored procedure, the JRXML, and the parameter names in the Java class, all have to be the same. In my case, the Java class used MIN_DATE and MAX_DATE while the storedproc and JRXML used minDate and maxDate.

No wonder the data wasn't being returned!